# How do I make these radially symmetrical edges longer?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, geometry, topology

Please refer to the screenshot.

It's the shape of a gearwheel in front ortho, currently just a circle to be extruded later.

[image: screenshot]

I would like for these to be as wide as indicated in the concept image in the back (black ink).

I tried scaling along local axes but none of that worked.

How do I do this?

EDIT:
It's probably hard to see in the original image, so I'm adding this one to show all the vertices

[image: all vertices highlighted]

Comment: If you have the shipped with Blender addon Add Mesh: Extra Objects activated, you might add a gear and modify the parameters to suit your requirements. There are tooltips in the Adjust Last Operation panel that explain what the names of the gear dimensions are used for. It will take some trial and error, but I think you should be able to get things to line up with your sketch.

Comment: If you select two of the verts on an edge and simply hit S they should scale apart along the edges correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you did when you say, "*I tried scaling along local axes but none of that worked.*"

This is how I would do it - scaling them individually:

1. Select the outer edges in *Edge Select* mode and make sure that *Transform Pivot Point* is set to *Individual Origins*.

   [image: individual origins]
2. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale them until the width is like you want it.

   [image: scale outer edges]
3. If the inner edges are too wide or narrow, select them.

   [image: select inner edges]
4. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> again to adjust their width as well.

   [image: scale inner edges]

If the radii of the outer or inner edges are not matching the concept image, you can select them and scale them with the *Transform Pivot Point* set back to the default *Median Point*.

[image: scale to median point]